Как авторизоваться в системе и парсить данные?
Я парсю данные с сайта, где надо предварительно войти в кабинет, а потом пользовательские данные парсить.
Пишу такой код:
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJarInterface;

$client = new Client();
$jar = new CookieJar();

 $response = $client->post('url/site.com/login/', [
            'form_params' => [
                'USER_LOGIN' => 'email@mail.com',
                'USER_PASSWORD' => 'pwd123',
                ''
            ],
            'cookies' => $jar, 
]);

$response = $client->get('url.site.com', [
    'cookies' => $jar, 
]);

$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadStr($response->getBody());
dd($dom->outerHtml);

В результате не получается войти в кабинет.
Форма, которая находится на сайте:
<form name="form_auth" method="post" target="_top" action="/login/?login=yes">
            <input type="hidden" name="AUTH_FORM" value="Y">
            <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="AUTH">
            <input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="/login/">
            <input type="hidden" name="USER_REMEMBER" value="Y">
            <input type="hidden" name="Login" value="Войти">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="USER_LOGIN" id="signinSrEmail" placeholder="Email" aria-label="Email address" required="" data-msg="Please enter a valid email address." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success" value=""> <input type="password" class="form-control" name="USER_PASSWORD" id="signinSrPassword" placeholder="********" aria-label="********" required="" autocomplete="off" data-msg="Your password is invalid. Please try again." data-error-class="u-has-error" data-success-class="u-has-success">

Как решить проблему?

$jar->toArray() до и после логина можно сравнить. Еще проверить, что имена сайта везде совпадают

Нужно смотреть какие еще данные передаются в POST запросе на сайте, и воспроизвести их в коде.
